# How to convert object that contains a member variable that is an array to an array of objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I want to convert this:

```
class ObjectWithArray
{
    int iSomeValue;
    SubObject[] arrSubs;
}

ObjectWithArray objWithArr;
```

to this:

```
class ObjectWithoutArray
{
    int iSomeValue;
    SubObject sub;
}

ObjectWithoutArray[] objNoArr;
```

where each objNoArr would have the same iSomeValue that objWithArr had, but a single SubObject that was in objWithArr.arrSubs;

The first idea that comes to mind is simply looping through objWithArr.arrSubs and using the current SubObject to create a new ObjectWithoutArray and adding that new object to an array.  But, I am wondering if there is any functionality in an existing framework to do this?

---

Also, how about simply breaking up ObjectWithArray objWithArr into ObjectWithArray[] arrObjWithArr where each arrObjectWithArr.arrSubs would contain only one SubObject from the original objWithArr?

Comment: Off-topic, but next time someone asks me what an oxymoron is, I'll definitely mention `ObjectWithoutArray[] objNoArr;`. Thank you for that.

Comment: Why do you want to do this at all, especially if every item is going to have the same `iSomeValue`?

Comment: I'm attempting to "massage" the object so that AutoMapper can map it to a different object that does not contain an array (e.g. ObjectWithoutArray).  The mapped-to objects will be later sorted and filtered to a specific subset based on the values of the SubObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would probably work.

```
class ObjectWithArray
{
    int iSomeValue;
    SubObject[] arrSubs;

    ObjectWithArray(){} //whatever you do for constructor


    public ObjectWithoutArray[] toNoArray(){
        ObjectWithoutArray[] retVal = new ObjectWithoutArray[arrSubs.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < arrSubs.length;  i++){
          retVal[i] = new ObjectWithoutArray(this.iSomeValue, arrSubs[i]);
        }

       return retVal;
    }
}

class ObjectWithoutArray
{
    int iSomeValue;
    SubObject sub;

    public ObjectWithoutArray(int iSomeValue, SubObject sub){
       this.iSomeValue = iSomeValue;
       this.sub = sub;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it pretty easily using Linq:

```
class ObjectWithArray
{
    int iSomeValue;
    SubObject[] arrSubs;

    ObjectWithArray() { } //whatever you do for constructor


    public ObjectWithoutArray[] toNoArray()
    {
        ObjectWithoutArray[] retVal = arrSubs.Select(sub => new ObjectWithoutArray(iSomeValue, sub)).ToArray();
        return retVal;
    }
}
```